# Authentication in URL for javascript

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, url

I am trying to write a simple script to obtain JSON data but the target requires login information in the actual URL like so:

http://login:password@URL/theapi

It appears that when using either getJSON or straight ajax the login details get skipped though even when passed on. I get an 401 error in developer tools in Chrome where it's interesting that the link in the error, when clicked, will actually go through and get he JSON data in to the browser

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

***Is there a way around this?***

Yes, while making the AJAX call, don't attach login:password in the url. Instead, add Authorization header with Base64 encoded value of login:password. This is how we can do using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://domain.tld",
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(login + ":" + password));
  }
});
```